# Border around Layout

Tags: border, vaadin7

I would like to draw a border (outline) around a VerticalLayout. I don't want all my VerticalLayout components to have borders, just one of them. It's a Vaadin 7 project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to do this is with CSS:

```java
VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout();
vl.addStyleName("layout-with-border");
```

And then modify your theme (.scss file) to include:

```css
.layout-with-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it dynamically without changing the theme file (.scss file):

```java
VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout();
final Styles styles = Page.getCurrent().getStyles();

String css = ".layout-with-border {\n" + 
            "    border: 1px solid black;\n" + 
            "}";

styles.add(css);
v1.addStyleName("layout-with-border");
```

Answer (score 0):

typically if there is a `getStyle()` then you can do something like

`vl.getStyle().set("border","1px solid black");`